# How to 301 redirect WP pages with a specific word in the URL

Tags: url, .htaccess, redirect

I've changed the URL structure of my WordPress pages (not posts) from:
mysite.com/pages/something-xxxxx to:
mysite.com/news/something-xxxxxx
I'd like to 301 redirect the old structure /pages/ to the new one /news/ via .htaccess.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use mod_rewrite in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I was wondering if I could redirect (remove from my URL's) the following extension: ?xxx The link is: mysite.com/news/something?xxx and it's supposed to be: mysite.com/news/something

Comment: you could add (remove space after 'http'): 
RewriteRule ^news/([^\?]*)\?.*$ http ://yoursite.com/news/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do do, I added this: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([^\?]*)\?.*$ http ://mysite.com/news/$1 [R=301,L] and I've got an Internat server error ?!?

Comment: you have to remove the space between 'http' and '://mysite.com' in the code ;)